# Find recursively a JSON value and return object

Tags: javascript

I've got some nested object data and I want to search it and return the matching object with parent based on the name.

My code works well if I want to search the children, but if I start to search it parent (Brands and Organizations, Media) I get  a empty Array.

JSON

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Brands and Organizations",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name":"Apple",
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name":"Iphone",
                            "parentId": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "id":3,
                    "name":"Samsung",
                    "parentId": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Media",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name":"CD",
                    "parentId": 4
                },
                 {
                    "id":6,
                    "name":"DVD",
                    "parentId": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Inlfuenser",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Javascript

```
function filterJson(categories, search) {

   var matches = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(categories)) return matches;

    categories.forEach(function(category) {

        if (category.name.includes(search)) {
            matches.push(category);
        } else {
            let childResults = filterJson(category.children, search);
            if (childResults.length)
                matches.push(Object.assign({}, category, { children: childResults }));
        }
    })

return matches;
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Yes, but I have the problem to get parent name if I start to search it etc Media

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about.  The parent name shows up in the return array see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgesn0fz/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to problem occurs when you type the caracters in different case, you can transform the search term to lowercase to resolve that issue.

```js
var object = {
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Brands and Organizations",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name":"Apple",
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name":"Iphone",
                            "parentId": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "id":3,
                    "name":"Samsung",
                    "parentId": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Media",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name":"CD",
                    "parentId": 4
                },
                 {
                    "id":6,
                    "name":"DVD",
                    "parentId": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Inlfuenser",
            "type": "dir",
            "children": null
        }
    ]
};


function filterJson(categories, search) {

   var search = search.toLowerCase().trim();
   var matches = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(categories)) return matches;

    categories.forEach(function(category) {

        if (category.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
            matches.push(category);
        } else {
            let childResults = filterJson(category.children, search);
            if (childResults.length)
                matches.push(Object.assign({}, category, { children: childResults }));
        }
    })

return matches;
}

function filter(value) {
console.log(value);
var matches = filterJson(object.categories, value);
console.log(matches);
document.getElementById('matches').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(matches);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="filter(this.value)" />

<div id="matches"></div>
```